# How to get the AWS credentials in a certain moment of a django error

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, credentials

I have a Django project deployed on AWS Lambda and I am trying to debug a certain S3 upload problem, but I want to know how to get the certain credentials during the error because it happens at random. I want to get credentials for a **past time**, For the next time the error appears I have the logging done in the code.
So how to get those credentials from the AWS console for a past period of time.
I see that my lambda-related-role has a 1hour update of credentials. and It changes in time.

Let me know if the question is offtopic.

Comment: How would this help you to debug the upload code?

Comment: I want to check if the credentials are rotated while my django deploy keeps the old keys. it is some problem in the django-storages https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/606